# MS-Access References When creating VBA macros

Tags: ms-access, printing, runtime-error

I've been trying to develop a system where an ms-access database comunicates with a brother ql-500 label printer to print a label based on data entered to a form, but for some reason, I am using the documentation for b-Pac, the "plugin" from brother created for this interfacing and i get a syntax error in ms-access, which leads me to think there might be some problem with the references. I checked and double checked and uninstalled the plugin and installed the plugin again, up to no solution...

My question here is, is there a way to check the references to see if it is the right file?

Im very new to access programming and this was asked to do in work...

EDIT: Over this one now, it was actually bad syntax, as i was refering to documentation from another version of the bPac plugin, it seems they have changed the syntax in one of the last versions...

Now i have another problem, a runtime error: -2147023782(800705a)

EDIT 2: i solved the problem, i uninstalled through control panel and then deleted remaining files manually and proceeded to install the b pac plugin again and it works now, thank you for your help though guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. I haven't worked with plugins so far.
In VBA window, go to : Tools > References

[image: tools > references]

This should bring up the following window :

[image: references dialog]

Check to see if your plugin is refered in there, or use Browse to locate and add it to the project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the thing here was i had already done that successfully, but im over this problem now as i found out it was happening due to some errors in the code, now im having a problem with a runtime error -2147023782(800705a), anyone familiar with this?

Comment: i solved the problem, i uninstalled through control panel and then deleted remaining files manually and proceeded to install the b pac plugin again and it works now, thank you for your help though guys ;)

Comment: You should edit your question to add that, it will be more easily visible for any other person stumbling upon this question. Good luck. :)